# Is it meaningful to use image sprites in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Since Chrome extensions load images from browser cache in the first place, is there any benefit of using image sprites in a Chrome extension? While image sprites are used to reduce xmlHttpRequests from img tags, `Chrome.extension.getURL(src)` will call xmlHttpRequest only to retrieve its image from browser cache.

Comment: Chrome extensions are not loaded from the browser cache, the files are saved when it is installed. chrome.runtime.getURL does not fetch anything, it converts a relative to an absolute url. Also, XHR has been replaced by [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Why am I seeing a status 200 to retrieve an image from my network panel? If there is no XHR like you mentioned, is there any benefit to use image sprites over individual images?

Comment: It may show up in the network panel but is actually from a local file if inside an extension package. No idea about sprites as I have never used them.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use sprite for non SEO related or icons images as it will reduce requests count even though it is not mandatory.